# How can i make those braces appear in a table? Watch that is included in two rows to form one single brace

Tags: tables

[image]

I can't add those braces to my table, I tried to make a `\begin{array}` inside a `\multirow` but it doesn't work, and now I'm desperate!

Comment: Could you post your code you have so far?  That would give us something to start from.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %
 \usepackage{blkarray}
 \usepackage{eqparbox} \newcommand{\ub}[1]{\underline{\bfseries#1}}

\begin{document}

\setlength\BAextrarowheight{1pt}
 \begin{blockarray}{ccl}
 \BAhline
 \begin{block}{c\BAmulticolumn{2}{c}}
 N\textsuperscript{o} & Rank \\
\end{block}%
 \BAhline \begin{block}{c c\}\BAmultirow{\eqboxwidth{L}}}
1 & \itshape\ub{8} & \eqmakebox[L]{run length = 2}\\
2 & \itshape\ub{9} & {}\\%
\end{block}%
\begin{block}{c c\}\BAmultirow{\eqboxwidth{L}}}
3 & \ub{7} & run length = 2\\
4 & \ub{6} & {}\\%
\end{block}%
 5 & 2 & \\%
 6 & 16 \\
 19 & 14 \\
 20 & 4\\ 21 & 13 \\
 22 & 26 \\
 28 & 24 \\%
 \begin{block}{c c\}\BAmultirow{\eqboxwidth{L}}}
 29& 22 & run length = 3 \\
 30 & 21 \\
31 & 20 \\
\end{block}
 \BAhline
\end{blockarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For an even "run length", I place a `$\left.<array>\right\}<text>$` construction on the lower line raised `.5\normalbaselineskip` into position (ensurin the result has no height/depth). For an odd "run length", I place a similar construction on the middle/centre line and `\smash` it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} r l @{} }
  \toprule
  No & \multicolumn{1}{c @{}}{Rank} \\
  \midrule
   1 & \underline{\itshape\bfseries 8} \\
   2 & \underline{\itshape\bfseries 9}%
       \raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$\left.\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \end{array}\right\}
               \mbox{run length = 2}$} \\
   3 & \underline{\bfseries 7} \\
   4 & \underline{\bfseries 6}%
       \raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$\left.\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \end{array}\right\}
               \mbox{run length = 2}$} \\
   5 & 28 \\
   6 & 16 \\
  19 & 15 \\
  20 &  4 \\
  21 & 13 \\
  22 & 26 \\
  28 & 24 \\
  29 & \underline{\itshape\bfseries 22} \\
  30 & \underline{\itshape\bfseries 21}%
       \smash{$\left.\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \end{array}\right\}
               \mbox{run length = 3}$} \\
  31 & \underline{\itshape\bfseries 20} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```